# How do you synchronize 2 threads doing database commits?

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle11g, content-management-system, request

I am currently working on customizing a content management system known as [Atlassian Confluence](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/ALLDOC/Atlassian+Documentation).

In this CMS you can do things like create/edit pages and upload files to pages and render them (like an image or ms office docs).

If you create a page and then edit it 10 times (click "Edit", enter some new text, click "Save" 10 times) the CMS will create 10 more versions of the same page.  So you essentially never lose anything.

However, I have been noticing this product occasionally will create 2, sometimes 3, new versions with only one edit! So of course I have been googling this and have found similar problems reported:

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-13480

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-10662

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-18970

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-9857

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-16732

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-18970

If I'm hearing what people are saying correctly - there are 2 or more threads that are inside a database transaction doing the same thing.  These threads cannot see each other until one commits to the database.  But for some reason the other thread doesn't stop and does a 2nd commit - so you end up with 2 or more versions of the same page edit.

How do I go about fixing this on our system ? Is there anything that can be done to prevent duplicate versions from being committed?

I am asking Content Management System experts in the stackoverflow community to please offer advice.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Confluence.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this problem need to be handled at the point the SAVE request is made and not while committng to the database Thread.

Im not a CMS expert but You need to Stop the Edits being saved when there are no Changes or once the 'Save' request already sent.

This will probably involve using to flag varible to indicate any change to the content and Allow save only when there are new changes. Else Disable the 'save' button or ignore the save request.

Thanks, Sunil

Answer (score -1):

First: this should be handled properly by the database, if it isn't handled properly, this is a bug of the CMS and not your code.

That said: as a workaround for that bug you need to create a bottle-neck thread that accessed the database, while all outside threads do not communicate to the database, but hand over all requests to this artificial bottle-neck instead. That thread then needs to use a construct like a LinkedBlockingQueue to ensure that only one request at a time is written (the duplication check should then be handled by the CMS).